# String to Date Parse

Tags: c#, datetime, azure, windows-phone-8.1

I have a problem. In Windows Phone 8.1 project this code works but in Windows Azure Cloud Services project won't work. This code get date from xml.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(xn.ChildNodes[4].InnerText, "ddd, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss UT", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

XML's date format is:

```
Sun, 29 Jun 2014 18:00:00 UT
```

Comment: How does it 'don't work' exactly?

Comment: You should try using `InvariantCulture`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. Because it seems your current culture is `tr-TR` and `Sun`, `Jun` is defined for English.